# python urllib / requests fails to download file but browser does

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to download this [zip file](http://prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov/../data_catalog/EBSA/ebsa_ocats_20150703.csv.zip).
The zip file downloads correctly via chrome but fails with a 400 Bad Request error using requests or urllib.

```
>> import requests
>> import urllib

>> url = 'http://prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov/../data_catalog/EBSA/ebsa_ocats_20150703.csv.zip'
>> r = requests.get(url)
>> r.ok
False
>> r.headers
{'content-length': '254', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)', 'connection': 'close', 'date': 'Tue, 07 Jul 2015 20:39:55 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'}
>> r
<Response [400]>
>> r.text
u'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">\n<html><head>\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />\n</p>\n<hr>\n<address>Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov Port 80</address>\n</body></html>\n'

>> z = urllib.urlopen(url)
>> z.read()
'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">\n<html><head>\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />\n</p>\n<hr>\n<address>Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov Port 80</address>\n</body></html>\n'
```

Things I have tried (and failed):

- spoofing the User-Agent header.
- persisting cookies by using a requests session

.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the extraneous /.. from the url. It works in a browser because browsers normalize urls for you. Without the /.. this works fine with either urllib or requests.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Firefox remove the ".." So the effective URL being requested is

```
http://prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov/data_catalog/EBSA/ebsa_ocats_20150703.csv.zip
```

Remove the .. in your request and it should work.