# Need help converting powershell commands that download zip file from url to python

Tags: python

As the title suggests I need to convert powershell commands that successfully downloaded a zip file from a sharepoint url to python.

Using the powershell in Windows to download a zip file from url works like a charm.

```
 > $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
 > $client.Headers.Add("Authorization","Bearer eyJ...")
 > $DownloadFilePath = "C:\path\to\file.zip"
 > $FileUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='sites/xxx/path/to/file.zip')/`$value"
 > $client.DownloadFile($FileUrl, $DownloadFilePath)
```

However, using python to download a zip file -- given the same url and token as above -- does not work. The code below produces a 400 error and an empty zip file.

```
import requests
FileUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='sites/xxx/path/to/file.zip')/`$value"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer eyJ..."
}
r = requests.get(FileUrl, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
with open(r"C:\path\to\file.zip", "wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
If I execute the below command in powershell

```
> $value
```

I get no response, but it is necessary in the url in order to produce a non-empty local zip file.

Comment: I don't know what you've elided with the `...`, but it looks like there are one or more variable substitutions in `"https://....zip')/\`$value"`. You'll need to get `$value` and whatever the `...zip')` thing is into your Python code so it can generate a valid URL. One without `'` and `)` and `$value`.

Comment: I think you're right and I've provided more information in the FileUrl. I only redacted some sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Url string contain `/../` ?
If yes, you need to remove these parts from your url string.
Explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279624/python-urllib-requests-fails-to-download-file-but-browser-does), though it is not the exact same problem.

Answer (score -1):

your code seems to work well , check your url , or use this code

```
import requests

print('Download Starting...')
 
url = 'http://www.url.com/file.ext'
 
r = requests.get(url)
 
filename = url.split('/')[-1] 
with open(filename,'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.content)
 
print('Download Completed!!!')
```